# What's the state-of-the-art for pagination with Sequel and Rails 4?

Tags: ruby, will-paginate, sequel, rails-api, kaminari

I have a Rails-API app using Sequel which needs pagination.  I've come across a few options but have ran into problems with each of them.

- [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) looks great, but appears to have no Sequel support.
- will_paginate appears to have Sequel support, but hasn't been updated for Rails 4 and seems to do messy things like polluting Array.
- The Sequel paginate extension works ok, but doesn't have any Rails integration or convenience methods (default per page, max per page, default ordering, parameter handling...)

I reckon I could...

- Swallow the pollution and use will_paginate.
- Write or find a kaminari-sequel gem.
- Write my own Sequel pagination Rails integration and convenience methods.
- Something I missed?

This project is on a tight schedule, is a very basic API service, and I would like to avoid as much yak shaving as possible.  Recommendations?